# Setting JNDI factory in solace queue consumer

Tags: spring-jms, solace

I have been given a factory to connect to a Solace queue.

I am using this dependency, within a spring-boot 2.7.7 application :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.solace.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>solace-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And so, I create this bean:

```
@Bean
public JndiObjectFactoryBean connectionFactory(JndiTemplate jndiTemplate) {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean connectionFactory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    connectionFactory.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate);
    connectionFactory.setJndiName(jndiName);
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

But I get:

> ClassNotFoundException : JMSContext

The reason is, solace-jms-spring-boot-starter:4.3.0 includes geronimo-jms_1.1_spec and JMSContext was added in JMS 2.0.

If add javax.jms.javax.jms-api, then it starts up, sometimes, as there are two versions of JMS in the same scope.

How should I create a JndiObjectFactoryBean with a jndiName? (without having repeated classes with different versions)

Comment: Can you see if this example helps you? https://github.com/SolaceProducts/solace-spring-boot/tree/master/solace-spring-boot-samples/solace-jms-sample-app-jndi